# EOSIO Tutorial : publishing contract error

Tags: smart-contract

I'm working on EOSIO tutorial 
and now I'm workingon https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/data-persistence part.

Right now, I'm stuck on deploying contract.

```
jongbok@DESKTOP-96ICBPJ:~/eos/contracts/addressbook$ cleos set contract addressbook /home/jongbok/eos/contracts/addressbook -p addressbook@active
Reading WASM from /home/jongbok/eos/contracts/addressbook/addressbook.wasm...
Publishing contract...
```

Terminal have to show transactions but it never proceeds.
Can anybody help for this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you figure out the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have the private key for account addressbook in your wallet?

Have you checked the abi file if it is not empty? the newer versions of CDT sometimes do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What should I check on abi file? I have an addressbook.abi file, but I'm not sure what should I check.

Comment: is the abi file empty? if not do you see all the entries in it?

Comment: Yes. I can see entries including upsert, erase, person

Comment: May I ask which test-net you're deploying it in?  It might just be a network issue or such

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I'm using Ubuntu, and I'm not sure which test-net I'm deploying it in. I also think it might be a network issue

Comment: i recommend junglenet for testing! http://monitor.jungletestnet.io/

Answer (score 1):

- Is `nodeos` running?
- What OS / build version are you on?

If keosd was not unlocked, you would be getting a permission error and it doesn't sound like the ABI is an issue yet because he hasn't pushed the contract.

You can add the flags `--print-request` `--print-response` to see where the communication with the chain is getting hung.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Nodeos is running and my version is v1.4.4 
My wallet is unlocked.
Where should I put flags(--print-request, --print-response)?

Comment: in the options block of the command `cleos set contract [OPTIONS] account [contract-dir] [wasm-file] [abi-file]`
That's weird that it just hangs like that.

Comment: Sorry for late replay. I guess it might be a network issue, so I'm trying it on other network. Thank you.